# How to creat the symbol `\not\Leftrightarrow`?

Tags: symbols

I want to type the symbol `\not\Leftrightarrow`. I tried with

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{cases}
A\cdot B \geqslant 0,\\
A \geqslant 0 \end{cases} \not\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
 B \geqslant 0,\\
A \geqslant 0.\
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think, it is not nice. How can I creat that symbol?

Comment: Consider using [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot).

Comment: Nowadays, you can also use `\nLeftrightarrow` instead if all you need is this one symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard method for it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\notleftright}{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\Leftrightarrow$\cr\hidewidth$/$\hidewidth}}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{cases}
A\cdot B \geqslant 0,\\
A \geqslant 0 \end{cases} \notleftright \begin{cases}
 B \geqslant 0,\\
A \geqslant 0.\
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]